# Handle Subversion error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, svn

I've connected my Android Studio with SVN and everything worked so far. Now there is following problem: 
I've added an image file to my drawable folder and added it also to the VCS. After that I moved the image file to the drawable-nodpi folder. 
If I want to commit my changes Android Studio says "...png is scheduled for addition, but is missing".

How can I handle this problem in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not realted to Android Studio at all. It's just SVN complaining about missing file stagged for commit. So if you changed your mind, unstage it

```
svn revert FILE
```

**EDIT**

> I don't know how to solve this with Android Studio. I don't have svn command

Andoid Studio is IntelliJ based so see their help:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/revert-changes-dialog.html

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is that I don't know how to solve this with Android Studio. I don't have svn command line tools. Is there an option in Android Studio?